# SOQL equivalent of countif

Tags: salesforce, soql

Is there something equivalent to the excel countif function (http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php) in SOQL ?

This is especially important in group by queries.

In oracle I would use the case function together with the case function

```
sum(
    case
         when (condition is true) 
          then 1 else 0 
  end
)
```

How do i perform the same in salesforce SOQL?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one place where SOQL is not the equal of SQL.  There is no CASE statement in SOQL, and there's really no way to accomplish a pivot here.  We recently solved a similar problem by querying all rows and then accumulating the pivoted values using Apex, and then exposing that as an Apex web service so we could call the query on demand.

Answer (score 0):

When using group by you could use [HAVING clause](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_having.htm) to filter the aggregate function by criteria.

Comment: Hi, I need to make something like a pivot table. So i don't want to filter out. I want to have a table where as rows i have a certain column i make group by and as column i want to have the age of the case when it was created. column 1) num of cases created this month case 2) num of cases created last month ...